# Alterar posição do marker do google maps ao clicar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou querendo alterar a posição do marcador do maps ao clicar na tela do Smartphone, no meu código em vez de alterar a posição ele cria vários marcadores.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

abaixo o codigo da main activity

```
package com.t2ti.localizacao;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0);
        longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0);


        setUpMapIfNeeded();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //setUpMapIfNeeded();
        //configura o zoom do mapa
        LatLng local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(local, 15);
        mMap.animateCamera(update);

        mMap .setOnMapClickListener( new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick (LatLng latLng) {
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() ;
                options.position( latLng ) ;
                mMap .addMarker( options ) ;

                //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Marker"));
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Marker"));
    }


}
```

Comment: Não entendi o voto negativo na pergunta.

Comment: zerei ela pra vc, agr nao ta negativa

Answer (score 1):

Consegui colocando a função clear da variável GoogleMap mMap no inicio do método onclick do map.

exemplo abaixo:

```
  mMap .setOnMapClickListener( new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick (LatLng latLng) {
            //função clear
            mMap.clear();
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() ;
            options.position( latLng ) ;
            mMap .addMarker( options ) ;

            //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Marker"));
        }
    });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Assim o marcador é movido.

Answer (score -1):

Você deve usar a CameraUpdate para fazer esses movimentos programáticos do mapa.

Para fazer isso, primeiro calcule os limites de todos os marcadores da seguinte forma:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (Marker marker : markers) {
    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

Em seguida, obtenha um objeto de movimento usando a factory `CameraUpdateFactory`

```
int padding = 0; // deslocamento das bordas do mapa em pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
```

Finalmente mova o mapa:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Ou se você quiser uma animação:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
```